# handling unchecked exceptions globally in project

Tags: java, exception

I an an telephonic interview of java the interviewer asked few questions regarding java exceptions in which one of the question he asked is How can you handle unchecked exceptions globally in project.?
now for this even i have to think for a moment by defining the custom error handler in java but this was not the correct answer , can you please advise how we can handle the unchecked exceptions globally in project..!

Comment: probably your interviewer was looking at [`Thread.setUnCaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a mind reader, but the interviewer was probably asking about exception handlers:

- You can set a global handler by calling the static method [`Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)), or
- You can set a thread-specific handler by calling [`setUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) on the individual thread, or
- If you are in a thread group, you can override [`ThreadGroup.uncaughtException()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable)) method (`ThreadGroup` implements the [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) interface).

Comment: +1 you are not a mind reader but your mind is definitely magical :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks a lot perfect expantion

Answer (score 2):

You can set `UnCaughtExceptionHandler` per `Thread` probably your interview was looking it to handle for main Thread

[`Thread.setUnCaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Comment: +1 good reasonable answer.

Comment: I'd have accepted that answer.